# About permissions to access to the LinkedIn Ads API

Tags: linkedin-api

I am currently trying to access the tables of an advertising account that I manage using the LinkedIn API.

Following the instructions I have obtained on the internet, I successfully connect to the LinkedIn Company API, but actually I am needing to be able to visualize the tables related to LinkedIn Ads to obtain information that I am currently needing regarding campaigns.

Investigating on the Internet, I realized that I probably need a permission called r_ad_campaigns to be able to access this type of tables, but I can not currently enable it.

Could you tell me how to connect specifically to the LinkedIn Ads API? It is worth noting that I have already taken the steps of the LinkedIn developer and have the credentials "Client ID" and "Client Secret".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

By "access the tables of an advertising account" do you mean that you are are looking for a way to report on your campaigns/accounts?

Not all APIs are available for open access. You can apply for access here and select your use case: https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner. If your use case is approved, you will be able to request additional scopes.